# Is "if zoomed out" a complete clause?

Tags: conditionals

Consider the following:

> The picture loses its quality *if zoomed out far enough*.

I found many instances of this on Google, but I dont see any subject in the *if* clause and I wonder if it's correct at all?

Comment: There is no finite verb either; the participle *zoomed* acts as if it is an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

In *The picture loses its quality if zoomed out far enough* there are two clauses. The first is the independent finite clause *The picture loses its quality*. The second is the dependent non-finite clause *if zoomed out far enough.* It’s another question whether a picture can be 'zoomed' or not, but that’s not a matter of grammar.

Comment: This is likely in a review for a camera, and whether it's the *it's* [the picture] or *[the camera]* that has been elided in the second clause is arguable.

Comment: Or it's just a picture which you are using a zoom tool on.

Answer (score 1):

"*If zoomed out*" is grammatical and it's a phrase.

To be exact, it's a participial phrase.

When we make participial phrases from adverbial clauses, we can remove the subject but keep the subordinator:

> The picture loses its quality **if zoomed out far enough**.

Or we can remove both:

> **Zoomed out far enough**, the picture loses its quality.